# How to cryptanalyze Bifid cipher?

Tags: classical-cipher, classical-cryptography

this is my first question.
I've been into classical cryptography for about a year or so, but I am getting started with cryptanalysis of these ciphers. I am trying to figure out how to reconstruct the Polybius square when performing a known-plaintext attack on the Bifid. Can you all help me out when it comes to this?

Comment: Which parts don't you get? There are tutorials online. Please make your questions specific.

Comment: Please state what your givens are; plaintext and ciphertext, or ciphertext only ? How long ? What are the assumptions made on plaintext ?